# How to Show user Order History in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, e-commerce

i have 2 table of order's

Orders Table

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('fname');
            $table->string('lname')->nullable();
            $table->string('address1');
            $table->string('address2')->nullable();
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('region');
            $table->string('postcode');
            $table->string('country');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('total');
            $table->string('paymentmode');
            $table->string('randomid');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                        ->onDelete('restrict')
                        ->onUpdate('restrict');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and productorders

```
Schema::create('productorders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('qty');
            $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')
                        ->onDelete('cascade')
                        ->onUpdate('restrict');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Here is my Order Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class order extends Model
{   
    public function user(){

      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');

    }

    public function order(){

         return $this->hasMany('App\productorder');

    }
}
```

here is productorder model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class productorder extends Model
{
    public function order(){

      return $this->belongsTo('App\order');

    }
}
```

orders has many productorders and productorders belongstoo order because there are multi product with each orders

order successfully completed but now i want to show order history ordered by user's

### Thanks

Comment: Your Model ? Controller ? ....

Comment: Do you have any Eloquent models set up?

Comment: Yes both have models i am adding models too now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Into your Users model, add following:

```
public function orders(){
  return $this->hasMany('\App\Orders');
}
```

Now, from controller, you may call

```
Auth::user()->orders();
```

This will return you Orders collection for user. Then you may compact it to the view and format as you like.
You also may use eager/lazy load to get additional detais on order.
Here you may find additional info on that: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships